# How can a reusable component in React be mocked in a way that has separate use case during integration

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a button that is a reusable component used in a component. I want to mock it in a way that I can test for both Previous and Next funtionality. I was able to mock it but I don't know how best to mock it for the same use case within the same test block.

```
const Button = ({
    name = "Submit",
    type = "button",
    onClick,
    onKeyPress,
    className,
    disabled = false,
    background,
    testId,
    ...props
}: ButtonProps) => {
    return (
        <button
            className={...}
            type={type}
            onClick={onClick}
            onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
            {...props}
            disabled={disabled}
            data-testid={testId ?? "button"}
        >
            {name}
        </button>
    );
};

export default Button;
```

I have two components inside another big components that I am testing. I need a way to efficiently mock and test both use case of button (previous and next)

```
const TestComponent = () => {
    return (
        <>
            {/* Other codes here */}
            <Button
               name="Back"
               className={...}
               onClick={handlePrevious}
               testId="previous"
            />

            <Button
               name="Next"
               className={...}
               onClick={handleNext}
               testId="next"
            />
        </>
    )
}
```

How I managed to mock the button inside the TestComponent.test.tsx file:

```
jest.mock("@/reusable/Button", () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation((props: ButtonProps) => {
        return (
            <button
                data-testid={props.testId ?? "button"}
                onClick={handleNext}
                disabled={props.disabled}
            >
                {props.name}
            </button>
        );
    });
});

describe('testing buttons', () => {
    {/* I could only test an instance of the implementation here (next) */}
}
```

I was able to do the above to mock the implementation of one instance of the button. I need a way to mock and test both use cases. Any idea will be welcome

Comment: If you want to test the user journey, it might be more suited to end-to-end testing. That way you can check that when the buttons are selected it navigates to the relevant thing. Otherwise you can just mock a function and pass it as a value to onClick and check that it has been called.

Comment: I understand your point. The thing is that I need a way to test both previous and next. I don't know how best to pass different values for different scenarios of the button since i am to check for two different interactions

Comment: Where do `handlePrevious` and `handleNext` come from in the component you want to test?